# How to implment role based authorizarion with React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, user-roles

I know this is not an usual requirement, but is it possible to create a role based authorization system using React Navigation? If yes, is there a complementary tool to achieve that? Or can this be made using only React Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do authorization rules using `react navigation` library.

Here are some good articles to follow:

- https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html

As I use `redux-saga`, I like to use it to control authentication flow, because it's easy to handle in a more linear way, listening to `redux-persist` actions

I think does not exists a *right way* to do this, because it depends a lot according with yours needs, application flow and backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate `react-navigation` with `redux`, you will be able to intercept all the navigation actions (with `navigate/` prefix. Eg: `navigate/HOME`) in a redux middleware. You can write your own logic in the middleware to only let authorized actions to reach the reducer.

Follow this guide for integrating react-navigation to redux - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html.

This video will help you with using middleware for this purpose - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjiu7Lgdg3s.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple logic.
Here is my logic which worked perfectly...

```
RequireAuth.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { authedUser } from '../../../helper/helpers';
import { Lang } from '../../../helper/Lang';
import Login from "../../screens/form/login";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Button,
  Icon,
  H1,
  H2,
  H3,
  Text,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body
} from "native-base";
import styles from "./styles";

const RequireAuth =(obj)=>{
  const Component=obj.component;
return class App extends Component {
        state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isLoading: true
        }
componentDidMount() {
            authedUser({loaduserow:false,noCatch:true}).then((res) => {
              if(res.loged){
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false});}
              else{
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: false, isLoading: false});}
            }).catch(() => {
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
            })
        }
  render() {
           const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = this.state;


           if(isLoading) {
               return(
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content padder>
          <H3 style={{marginTop:20,marginBottom:30, borderBottomWidth: 1}}>Authenticating...</H3>
        </Content>
      </Container>)
           }
           if(!isAuthenticated) {
               return <Login {...this.props} />
           }
           return <Component {...this.props} />

  }
}}

export default RequireAuth;
```

src/App.js

```
....
import RequireAuth from "./screens/wall/RequireAuth";
...
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    About: { screen: About },
    Profile: { screen: RequireAuth({component:Profile,name:'Profile'}) },
.....
```

`authedUser()` is just a simple promise which return `resolve({loged:true})` if authed while not auths it returns `resolve({loged:false})`

Comment: This is authentication.  The OP asked for role based **authorization**.

Answer (score -1):

Check this below this might help you

```
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/01/react-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example
```